# Drawing to HTML canvas growing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw to an HTML canvas. I input 50 circles and a bunch of lines within a 1000x1000 px canvas. All circles should appear. instead i get this
[image]

What i believe is happening is that the things are being drawn to canvas of default size, then the canvas is grown. Except my Style tag is way before any JavaScript code to draw to the canvas. how do i fix this

My code bits:(writeen through Servlet)

```
out.println("<style> \n canvas{\nheight:1000px;\nwidth:1000px;\n}\n</style>");
out.println("<canvas id=\"c\" style=\"border:1px solid #000000;\">Test</canvas>");
process(render, out);
public void process(String input, PrintWriter out)
{
    out.println("<p id=\"input\" style = \"display:none\">"+input+"</p>");
    out.println("<script>\n"+
    "var JSONProcess = function(){\n" +
    "   var JSONInfo = document.getElementById(\"input\");\n" +
    "   var Json = JSON.parse(JSONInfo.innerHTML);\n" +
    "   var canvas = document.getElementById(\"c\");\n" +
    "   var c = canvas.getContext(\"2d\");\n" +
    "   if(Json.nodes != null)\n" +
    "   {\n" +
    "       var n = Json.nodes;\n" +
    "       for(var i=0; i< n.length; i++)\n" +
    "       {\n" +
    "           c.beginPath();\n" +
    "           c.arc(n[i].x+500,n[i].y+500,n[i].size,0,2*Math.PI, false);\n" +
    "           c.stroke();\n" +
    "       }\n" +
    "   }\n" +
    "   if(Json.edges != null)\n" +
    "   {\n" +
    "       var e = Json.edges;\n" +
    "       for(var i=0; i< n.length; i++)\n" +
    "       {\n" +
    "           var s = e[i].source;\n" +
    "           var t = e[i].target;\n" +
    "           c.beginPath();\n" +
    "           c.moveTo(s.x+500, s.y+500);\n" +
    "           c.lineTo(t.x+500, t.y+500);\n" +
    "           c.stroke();\n" +
    "       }\n" +
    "   }\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "JSONProcess();</script>");

      }
```

All input values are corrected i have read through them. The x and y values range from -500 to 500 which i shift so they fit on a canvas with values from 0-1000

Comment: Please show us some code. There is no way of guessing what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you pasted your code, but make sure you have the height and width attributes set on the canvas element.

Comment: its a bit broken up, give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

in HTML5  canvas height and width are not defined through style. They are defined separately. 
it has to be `out.println("<canvas id=\"c\" height =\"1000\" width=\"1000\" style=\"border:1px solid #000000;\">Test</canvas>");`